# Boundary Value Analysis: Why would you test valid values inside the boundary?

Tags: test-design, techniques, test-techniques

I can't understand why to use two values inside the boundary when using Boundary Value Analysis. For instance, suppose a program has the requirement: **Values between 1 and 100 are true, while all other values are false**.

`func calc(x):
  if (x >= 1 and x <= 100):
    return True
  else:
    return False`

A lot of books ([Pressman](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0078022126), for instance) say you have to use the inputs 0, 1, 2, 99, 100 and 101 to test such a program.

So, my question is: Why use the inputs '2' and '99'? I tried to make a program with a fault such that the test case set (0, 1, 2, 99, 100 and 101) exposes a failure and the test case set (0, 1, 100, 101) does not expose it, but I can't make such program.

Could you make such program? If not, it is a waste of resources to create redundant test cases '2' and '99'.

Comment: "I tried to make a program with a fault such that the test case set (0, 1, 2, 99, 100 and 101) exposes a failure and the test case set (0, 1, 100, 101) does not expose it, but I can't make such program." - you haven't tried hard enough. If (x == 2) return false.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Can you please explain how x=2 is giving false for above program?

Comment: @aLearner - the OP wrote "could you make such program?" I just did. In Black Box testing, you don't read the code. Imagine a program that had what I wrote in it.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere not quite right, since 0 and 101 also need to return false. See my answer ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your example, yes, it might be overkill **if you are performing white-box testing**. However, if you couldn't read or didn't have access to the code (i.e. black-box testing), these tests would be very useful to make sure, for example, that the implementation didn't look like:

```
func calc(x):
  if (x == 1 or x == 100):
    return True
  else:
    return False
```

So it really depends on the bigger picture of how you are designing your tests. By all means, if you're performing white-box testing, you should use the knowledge of how the code is actually written to ensure you don't write lots of extra tests because a book says to. You will likely come up with **different** (not necessarily fewer) tests when doing white-box testing to ensure things like statement and branch coverage.

For black-box testing on the other hand, it's often helpful to assume nothing. Especially if you don't know the quality of the codebase. I once worked on a project where a spinning object had problems in a "magic" RPM range that we could only have found by testing since we didn't have access to the actual firmware involved. Fixing it from our end was equally...entertaining.

Comment: Ok, imagine ou are build a blackbox test. Why to use the values 2 and 99 if the values 1 and 100 are boundary true values. I present the code to show an implementation and help to think about an incorrect program that the tests (0,1,2, 99,100,101) gets a failure and the tests (0,1,100,101) does not get it

Comment: I believe my code example does just that. Passing 1 or 100 would return true, passing 0 or 101 would return false, so the tests would pass if that was all you used. But 2 and 99 would also return false, causing the test to fail.

Comment: @VictorVidigalRibeiro I just realized that my code is only two characters different than yours, so I'll point out the difference. Note that I used `==`, not `>=` and `<=`. :)

Comment: Yeahh, It is the example: with == operator. Thanks...

Comment: Checking 1 and 100 is useful even with white-box testing. The purpose of a test is to validate the current implementation and to prevent a regression when the code is modified. Besides, having a useless test is cheap compared to a missing test which could lead to hours of debugging.

Comment: Yep, 1 and 100 are useful regardless. I believe the OP was mainly concerned with the additional tests _inside_ the valid range but not at the boundary, specifically 2 and 9 in this example.

Comment: The same goes with 2 and 9, it's as much useful as 1 and 100 even with white-box testing. I was trying to express my disagreement about your statement on white-box testing. The literature usually tells to test the smallest set of inputs to cover all the branches, but it's forgetting that in reality the code tested today will most likely change tomorrow. So one test might seem redundant for the current implementation where in reality it's a test to prevent a regression.

Comment: @FlorentB. Yes, I agree that it's good for preventing regressions, though in practice there are things that are less likely to break than others. Really the point is to apply critical thinking when designing test cases: you shouldn't _add_ tests that are redundant just because you're going "by the book", but you also shouldn't _skip_ tests that could be important for other reasons, such as regression like you mentioned. I think we're violently in agreement :)

Comment: I agree on that if by "critical thinking" you mean writing the sufficient amount of tests to address the expected level of quality/reliability which goes from the critical/happy path to the utopic 100% use cases. What I disagree on, is when you are insinuating that a white test case should have less tests compared to black box testing, when it should be the opposite. White box testing should include all the black-box tests + the ones specific to the known implementation/branching. You can't exclude a test just because it looks redundant when looking at the code.

Comment: The minimum test set here should be 0, 1, 2, 99, 100 and 101, with white-box or black-box testing (that is assuming x can't be a float).

Comment: @FlorentB for this particular (trivial) example, I really don't have a strong opinion. I did specifically say you would likely end up with different, _not necessarily fewer_ tests when doing white-box testing. I've just seen too many useless tests where someone wanted to test the same functionality over and over again ad nauseum while changing a parameter that didn't actually affect the code path being taken, which is why my _general_ point is to apply critical thinking rather than just going by a book.

Answer (score 6):

We took 0 and 101 to test for **INVALID** data scenario.

We took 1 and 100 to test whether **= part** of <= and >= is working or not.

We took 2 and 99 to test whether VALID values are also working in(**best case scenario**) or not. You can treat this as a positive test case.

So three test cases scenario would be there:

1) for INVALID values.

2) for exact boundary values.

3) for VALID values.

Actually your example is very simple so by checking with 2 and 99 may seem redundant. But there may be cases which can be complex in real scenarios. So in those cases along testing with INVALID and exact boundary data values, it is also necessary to check with VALID data values.